# Find all "tame" solutions of $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2(f(x)+f(y))$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

**Question:** Find all "tame" solutions of $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2(f(x)+f(y))$.

---

This is how I've tried to begin—
Plug in $y=0$ to get $f(0)=0$.

$y\to x$ gives $f(2x)=2^2f(x)$. Also, I've noted that $f$ is an even function by $y\to -x$ substitution.

Now, I somewhat think that $f(kx)=k^2f(x)$ but I'm not sure how to land onto there. 
And at the end of the day, I believe $f(x)=ax^2$ but I cannot proceed into that stage.

Comment: Inductively, suppose that we know $f(kx)=k^2f(x)$ for $k≤n$.  Then let $y=nx$.  We have $f((n+1)x+f((n-1)x)=2\left(f(x)+f(nx)\right)\implies f((n+1)x+(n-1)^2f(x)=2f(x)+2n^2f(x)$ and the desired result follows at least for integers $k$.

Comment: Fine, I get it.

Comment: Well, what I wrote is far from a complete solution.  Next step is to show it holds for rational $k$.  Then, I suppose, invoke continuity (unstated but I figure that is what "tame" means) to show it works for all $k$.

Comment: @lulu Yes I got that.

Comment: If "*tame*" includes continuous differentiability, then taking the derivative in $x$ on both sides gives $f'(x+y)+f'(x-y)=2f'(x)\,$, which after a little more work implies that $f'$ is linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a good start, but not sure where to go from there. My approach may help you.

Let $$e(x,y) := f(x+y)+f(x-y)-2(f(x)+f(y)). $$

We are given that $\;e(x,y)=0\;$ for all $\;x,y.\;$

Since $\;e(0,0) = -2f(0),\;$ then $\;f(0)=0.\;$ Since $\;e(0,x) = -2f(0) + f(-x) -f(x),\;$ then $\;f(-x) = f(x).\;$ Let

$$ g(x,y) := f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y). $$

Now evaluate to get

$$ 2(g(x_1,y)+g(x_2,y)-g(x_1+x_2,y)) = \\
e(x_1,x_2)+e(x_1+x_2+y,y)-e(x_1+y,x_2+y), $$

but this is $0$ by property of $\;e(x,y).\;$
Thus, $\;h(x):=g(x,y)\;$ satisfies [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), and assuming $h(x)$ is "tame", then
$\;h(x) = g(x,y) = x\, c(y)$ for some function $c(y).$ Using the same reasoning with
$\;h(y) := g(x,y)\;$ we have $\;g(x,y)=y\,d(x)\;$
for some function $d(x).$ Thus,
$\;g(x,y) = t\,xy\;$ for some constant $t.\;$ Now $\;\lim_{y\to0} g(x,y)/y = t\,x $
and, assuming $f'(0)$ exists, by definition, also $\lim_{y\to0} g(x,y)/y = f'(x)-f'(0).\;$ But $f(-x)=f(x)$ so $f'(0)=0$ and thus $f'(x)=t\,x\;$
and $f(x)=t\,x^2/2.$

Comment: could you prove that the only nonnegative functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_0^+$ which satisfy the quadratic functional equation of the OP are $f(x)=kx^2\;\;\forall\;x\in\mathbb R\;?$ $f(rx)=r^2f(x)\;\;\forall\;r\in\mathbb Q\;$ implies that $f(r)=kr^2\;\;\forall\;r\in\mathbb Q\;$ where $k=f(1).\;$ Could you prove that $f(x)=kx^2\;$ for any $\;x\in\mathbb R\;,\;$ not only for any $x\in\mathbb Q\;,\;$ by using the fact the $f$ is nonnnegative without using the continuity ?